# How to looping image grid 2 column in dompdf

Tags: php, image, loops, codeigniter, dompdf

```
<table style="background :blue; overflow: hidden; page-break-after:always;">
            <?php
                foreach($photos as $photo){

                    $path = 'uploads/foto/'.$photo->nama_foto_dir;
                    $type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                    $data = file_get_contents($path);
                    $putu = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);


            ?>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding:5px;"><?php echo $photo->nama_foto; ?>
                <div style="width:350px; height:300px; min-height:300px;"><img src="<?php echo $putu?>" style="height:300px;width:350px;"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <?php }?>
        </table>
```

I want to make the looping photo in 2 columns as shown in the screenshot below, can you help me solve the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<table style="background :blue; overflow: hidden; page-break-after:always;">
<?php
$i = 1;
foreach ($photos as $photo) {

    $path = 'uploads/foto/' . $photo->nama_foto_dir;
    $type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $data = file_get_contents($path);
    $putu = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
?>
    <?php if ($i / 2 == 0) { ?>
        <tr>
        <?php } ?>
        <td style="padding:5px;"><?php echo $photo->nama_foto; ?>
            <div style="width:350px; height:300px; min-height:300px;"><img src="<?php echo $putu ?>" style="height:300px;width:350px;"></div>
        </td>
        <?php if ($i / 2 == 0) { ?>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
<?php $i++;
} ?>
```